# Static helper function to set a property on another object

Tags: typescript, static, helper

A situation has come up in which we have a block of code that will be repeated in multiple files, and this block of code has to:

1. Create some object based on the values of other controls/properties.
2. Set a property on another object to be the object from #1.

Here is an example of what this looks like:

---

**Repeated code before refactoring** (TypeScript)

```
public class PageViewModel {
  private _name: TextBox;
  private _type: TextBox;
  private _timestampFormat: RadioButton;

  ..

  // This should generate a data model out of the current state of its controls.
  public generateDataModel(): IDataModel {
    // Here will be some logic to generate a property value based on
    // the radio button value and some other conditions.
    let timestampProperty;
    if (this._radioControl.value() === 1) {
      timestampProperty = { format: "foo" };
    } else if(this._radioControl.value() === 2) {
      timestampProperty = { format: "bar" };
    }

    var dataModelObject = <IDataModel>{
      name: this._name.value(),
      type: this._type.value(),
      timestamp: timestampProperty
    };
    return dataModelObject;
  }

}
```

---

**Problem**

The `generateDataModel` function will be present on more than one view model, all of which will generate the timestamp field from the radio control with that logic, so code will be repeated.

---

**How it was solved**

A helper method was extracted to do both #1 and #2 from above. This method is being called with references to both the control and the `IDataModel` object being created.

Helpers.ts:

```
public static setTimestampRadioButton(radioControl: RadioButton, dataModelObject: IDataModel): void {
    let timestampProperty;
    if (radioControl.value() === 1) {
      timestampProperty = { format: "foo" };
    } else if(radioControl.value() === 2) {
      timestampProperty = { format: "bar" };
    }

    dataModelObject.timestamp = timestampProperty;
}
```

PageViewModel.ts:

```
public generateDataModel(): IDataModel {
  var dataModelObject = <IDataModel>{
    name: this._name.value(),
    type: this._type.value()
  };

  Helpers.setTimestampRadioButton(this._radioControl, dataModelObject);

  return dataModelObject;
}
```

---

I have some concerns with this approach from the point of view of readability, and also because I think Helpers.ts knows too much about `IDataModel` and how it is used.

**My questions:**

1. Is this a good way to solve the problem of repetition here? Why / why not?

   - If not, is there a better way you'd suggest?
2. What do you think of the pattern `static setSomethingOnSomethingElse(thing1, thing2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that `setTimestampRadioButton` can be improved in three ways.

1. Side effects. By mutating the passed `dataModelObject`, the function immediately makes any function that uses `setTimestampRadioButton` harder to understand as it magically sets a property name that the calling function did not specify.
2. Typing. Mutating the argument the function forces you to create a `Partial<IDataModel>` (or cast an object which is *not* an `IDataModel` to `IDataModel`). This is not ideal.
3. Alternative property names. Currently only `IDataModel` uses the format from a `RadioButton`, what happens when `ITimeModel` needs the timestamp format stored in a `format` property? We are now back to the original problem.

I would instead recommend creating a method to get the expected format.

```
public static getTimestampFormat(radioControl: RadioButton): IFormat {
    if (radioControl.value() === 1) {
      return { format: "foo" };
    } else if(radioControl.value() === 2) {
      return { format: "bar" };
    }
    return { format: 
}
```

This simplifies your `generateDataModel` method even more.

```
public generateDataModel(): IDataModel {
  return {
    name: this._name.value(),
    type: this._type.value(),
    timestamp: Helpers.getTimestampFormat(this._radioControl)
  };
}
```

Instead of a static helper method, you might also consider adding the method as an instance method of the `RadioButton` class, or creating a child of the `RadioButton` class with a `TimestampRadioButton` class.

A couple other general things:

- Avoid casting like the plague. It is *almost* as bad as using the `any` type as it hides potential problems in a very similar way.
- I can't think of any instance in which adding `Object` or `data` to a variable name makes it more descriptive. `dataModelObject` doesn't really tell you any more than `model`.

Comment: Thanks @Gerrit0. To be clear, I changed the variable names in this example to abstract it away, but we don't use names like `dataModelObject`. Out of interest though, why is casting bad in this case? (I assume you're talking about the `<IDataModel>` cast before the object literal)

Comment: Good question @peter, take a look at [this playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Item%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%2F%2F%20No%20need%20to%20cast%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20()%3A%20Item%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%20id%3A%201%20%7D)%0D%0A%2F%2F%20No%20compiler%20error%2C%20likely%20runtime%20error%0D%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20()%3A%20Item%20%3D%3E%20(%3CItem%3E%7B%7D)%0D%0A%2F%2F%20The%20compiler%20knows%20something's%20up%20since%20we%20didn't%20cast%0D%0Alet%20c%20%3D%20()%3A%20Item%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%7D)%0D%0A) to see. Casting makes the compiler ignore type errors.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - great point. I will keep this in mind.